# Getting error "reference to non-static member function must be called" when calling push on priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

This might be an obvious issue but being a novice to C++ I'm not quite sure why this error occurs.

I have the following setup, I use a `priority_queue` that I typedef like this:

```
typedef priority_queue<int,vector<int>,PayloadIndexComparison> PayloadIndexPQ;
```

Then, I have a class that is using this priority queue:

```
struct MappingTechnique {

   vector<double> currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights;
   PayloadIndexPQ payloadIndexPQ(PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights));

   MappingTechnique() {
      for (int i = 0; i < PAYLOAD_SIZE; i++) {
         payloadIndexPQ.push(i); // this line gives an error
      }
   }
}
```

This code however gives the following error:

> error: **reference to non-static member function must be called**
>   `payloadIndexPQ.push(i);`

Does anybody know why this happens? I used the the same priority queue in code elsewhere and could call `push` without problems, so I suspect that it's due to the fact that I am calling this within the constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
PayloadIndexPQ 
payloadIndexPQ( PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights) );
```

defines a function, not an object, see [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Use `{` `}` instead

```
PayloadIndexPQ 
payloadIndexPQ{ PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights) };
```

The fact is that

```
PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights)
```

is considered a (functional) cast of `&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights`, so the end result is that of defining a function taking a reference to a `PayloadIndexComparison`. It is like declaring

```
int f(int(&x)); // declares basically void f(int& x); and not an integer
```

See the link for more details.

Comment: thanks! the hint with using curly braces solved it!!

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
PayloadIndexPQ payloadIndexPQ(PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights));
```

is interpreted as a function declaration. It is a function named `playloadIndexPQ` that takes a reference to a `PayloadIndexComparision` object named `currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights`.

I know, it's pretty weird. But since you're in the class definition you can't declare variables using an expression list `(...)` anyway. You can declare the variable and initialize it in the *ctor-initializer* of a default-constructor.

```
struct MappingTechnique {
    MappingTechnique() : payloadIndexPQ(PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights))
    { }
    // ...
};
```

In C++11 you have two extra options. You can have a brace-or-equal initializer so that the data member can be defined where it is declared:

```
PayloadIndexPQ payloadIndexPQ = PayloadIndexComparison(&currentAccumulatedPayloadIndexWeights);
// or PayloadIndexPQ payloadIndexPQ{ ... }
```

Comment: This is in a NSDMI, so you can't use the `()` form anyway. Extra pair of parens won't work.

Comment: @T.C. Right, I thought the code was in a function. Let me correct that.

Comment: Hey note there is some discussion in Meta regarding you removing some good posts of yours : ) [User deleted helpful answers because of `Down for non-existent maintenance.`?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295422/)